# Prove an infinite periodic continued fraction converges?

Tags: real-analysis, continued-fractions

I've been working through some problems in analysis to try and get a better grasp on the topic. One problem that I came across was the following:

> Choose $a_1,a_2,...,a_k \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $a_i > 0$ for all $i$ and $\prod_{i=1}^k a_i > 1$. Starting from any $x_1 > 0$, define a sequence $\{x_n\}$ by the continued fraction
>   $$
> x_n = \frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{\cdots + \frac{1}{a_k + x_{n-1}}}}}$$
>   Prove that $\{x_n\}$ converges.

This problem is a multiple part problem, where earlier we were asked to prove that if a function $f: I \to I$ on a closed interval $I$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $M < 1$, then the sequence defined as $\{x_{n+1}\} = f(x_n)$ converges.

Hence I was thinking that to prove the above statement I could prove that the recurrence relation above is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $M < 1$, whence convergence follows, but I'm not sure how to algebraically prove it's Lipschitz. Is this a viable solution? How would one prove this?

Answer (score 2):

For $x,y > 0$, we have for all $i$ that:

\begin{align*}
d \left(\frac1{a_i+x}, \frac1{a_i+y}\right) &= \left|\frac{(a_i+y) - (a_i+x)}{(a_i+x)(a_i+y)}\right| \\
&= \frac{d(x,y)}{(a_i+x)(a_i+y)}\\
&\le a_i^{-2} d(x,y)
\end{align*}

It follows that $d(x_{n+1},x_n) \le \prod\limits_{i=1}^k a_i^{-2} d(x_n, x_{n-1})$ so that this product may serve as the desired Lipschitz constant.